# How can I use svg graphics in a responsive wordpress page and get them to behave the same way the bitmaps do?

Tags: wordpress, svg

I've been doing a little hacking with wordpress ..via the editor.

I'm placing svg images and I've installed the SVG Support plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/

When I insert a regular image (a png file) the code looks like this:

```
<img class="alignnone wp-image-146 size-medium" 
src="mydomain/2-300x246.png" alt="2" width="300" height="246" />
```

and then the theme I'm using scales it as the browser scales up and down, which is what I desire with the svg image.

When I insert an SVG file, it does not show up until I modify the code by taking out the first class tag and add a new class tag:

```
class="style-svg"
```

like this..

```
<img class="style-svg" 
src="mydomain/convo_and_notes2.svg" alt="convo_and_notes" width="1" height="1" />
```

Maybe I need to use a different wordpress theme or modify the one I'm using.. but first I want to know is it possible to get the same responsive behavior from an SVG file (I'm guessing it is ...but how?)

The wordpress theme I'm using is Flat by YoArts if that's helpful information.

Sorry if this is not the right way to phrase this question.. I'm not sure what I'm doing so it's hard to know what to ask.

In a nutshell, I want the SVG files to behave like the bitmaps and would love some advice on how to do that.

Comment: I think I may have figured out the problem. I just needed to first embarrass myself by posting an easy question here on stackoverflow. I took the width and height out of my svg images image tag and replaced it with just width="300px" I also put the class="alignnone wp-image-146 size-medium" back in the img tag and it works as expected. I think the svg support plugin was adding the height and width of "1" for me and I just didn't change it properly. So, it was there, just too small to see. 
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-146 size-medium" src="file.svg" alt="convo_and_notes" width="300px" />

Comment: I'm going to leave the question though since I couldn't find anything about this particular problem when I searched and I'm sure somebody can come up with an eloquent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress uploader adds

```
height="1" wudth="1"
```

remove that and add

```
width="300px"
```

or something like that.

also to keep the responsive behavior don't remove the

```
class=""alignnone wp-image-146 size-medium"
```

that's it. The height and width were causing the problem.